# overscroll-behavior property is not working on webview

Tags: html, css, webview, android-webview, overscroll

I have a fixed positioned modal with flex layout in my website wherein user can type content. I've included `overscroll-behaviour-y: none` to the modal to prevent the underlying page from scrolling and to suppress refresh on scroll of text-content. Though, it works well with chrome, it doesn't work with webview resulting in page refresh when user types a huge amount of data and tries to scroll up. I've tried including `overscroll-behaviour` property to all parent elements including the html and body as well but it has no effect. Is there something wrong with my approach?

This is my sample modal css

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 110;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: white;
overscroll-behavior-y: none;
z-index: 115;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-overscroll-behavior

Safari still does not support this prop FYI.